# Fix above space when figure comes at the top of the page

Tags: white-space

When a figures comes at the top of a page, then it takes ~ -3 or -4 points by auto, my code and screenshots are follows:

[image]

and the code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe,graphicx,stfloats}

\begin{document}
\markboth{Test}{Trial}
First and foremost, \ref{chapter one} I want to thank my amazing colleagues at the
University of Cincinnati for their help with this book, especially
Zvi Biener, Vanessa Carbonell, Anthony Chemero, Valerie
Hardcastle, John McEvoy, Thomas Polger, Robert Richardson, Robert
Skipper, and George Uetz in biology. Guilherme Sanches de Oliveira
provided research assistance and help with indexing. I also
received tremendously helpful feedback from the graduate students
and faculty who participated in my seminar on idealization in the
autumn of 2014, including some of those named above, as well as
Frank Faries, Maurice Lamb, Vicente Raja Galian, Walter
Stepanenko, and Richard Stephenson \ref{section one}.

\newpage

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}
%{\centering\includegraphics{V:/530_ucp/67957.tex_black_LIVE/67957_Active/67957_core/67957_art/chi-potochnik-fig01001.eps}}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:[image]

I need to keep the white space for all the pages even any float comes at top of the page, how can I fix that? please suggest...

Comment: I changed your example to use a standard test image so anyone can run it, but I do not understand the question. the space above `First` is not affected by the figure which goes to the next page?

Comment: The space at the top of the page is specified to the _baseline_ of the first line of text so to the bottom of the `F` not the space above the `F` that you marked in your image. That specification doesn't directly apply if the first thing on the page is a large unit like an image, you do not want the baseline at the image at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure has nothing to do with the “problem”.

The first line on a page has its baseline at `\topskip` distance from the top border of the type block. With 10pt size, `\topskip` is set to 10pt, which is more than the height of a capital letter.

In the case of the figure, the first baseline is pushed down to accommodate the big object, which therefore ends up touching the top margin.

You *could* do

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\topskip}{\fontcharht\font`T}}
```

in the preamble, but I wouldn't. This of course requires changing the text height so it still contains an integer number of lines; so it could be

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtolength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\topskip}%
  \setlength{\topskip}{\fontcharht\font`T}%
}
```